# Cannot call value of non-function type '[String : String]'

Tags: swift

[image]

I am new to iOS & swift.So i don't understand what is the actual problem is.I am trying to use socket to check who are typing in chat App.

Comment: your Void return should be for your completionHandler, not for getTypingUser function.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Have you solved you problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.0**

Closure is we can say that function as argument, So function have parameter and return type also.

As per your code you missed to specify the return type of function, If closure return nothing than you must have to defined **Void** return type.

```
func getTypingUser(_ completionHandler: ([String: String]) -> ()) {
    guard let typingUser = dataArray[0] as? [String : String] else { return }
    completionHandler(typingUser)
}
```